# How to pass parameter value with "&" symbol in URL

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I have created the paginated report with parameter, 
And below are the sample url I used to pass parameter value through URL

https://app.powerbi.com/groups/1-a337-71d561f7faf5?rp:Country=IN&rp:Region=asia&Africa

From the above , IF the parameter value have "&" symbol , 
url not passing value to the parameter Region

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify Region twice to pass two values to this parameter.

https://app.powerbi.com/groups/1-a337-71d561f7faf5?rp:Country=IN&rp:Region=asia&rp:Region=Africa

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-url-pass-parameters